# Spring Social Facebook - No beans of 'Facebook' type found

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm trying to integrate Facebook registration and login into my Spring Boot webbapp and as I understood well the easiest way to do so is by using spring-social-facebook. 
I followed this code https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/spring-facebook-example
but I have a problem with the Facebook bean type which can't be found.

- Java version is 1.8
- spring-boot-starter-parent version is 2.0.6.RELEASE
- spring-social-facebook version is 2.0.3.RELEASE

The code in which I'm using Facebook object is this:

package com.job.jobwebapp.web;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fb")
public class FacebookController {

    @Autowired
    private Facebook facebook;

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute(facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList homeFeed = facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", homeFeed);
        return "feeds";
    }
}
```

Facebook attribute is underlined and its error message is this:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'Facebook' type found.

I don't have any social configuration class. The only place where I mention Facebook is within this controller class.

Comment: Don't. Spring Security has OAuth2 support out-of-the-box which you should prefer over the Spring Social Facebook API. It hasn't seen a release in 2 years. For facebook itself, use the "native" Facebook API (which you would still need to configure).

Comment: Make sure you follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start

Comment: @M.Deinum ok thank you very much! Do you know a good guide to follow? Right know I'm just using Spring Security without OAuth2... should I use it?